# pydantic - (de)serialize list to dict

Tags: python, serialization, deserialization, pydantic

**With:** Pydantic, (de)serializing to/from JSON

*Goal:* deserialize a List of objects, to a dictionary, lifting a property on the child object, as the key in the dictionary for the serialized form, and of course back again when deserializing.

**Example:**

I have a class model

```py
import uuid
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Recipe(BaseModel):
    id: uuid.UUID
    name: str
    description: str

class CountryDetails(BaseModel):
    name: str
    recipes: List[Recipe]
```

I am after the JSON to look like

```json
{
  "name": "australia",
  "recipes": {
    "a1acd620-0e87-4cbe-8d15-a4a3aff00cc3": {
      "name": "shrimp on the barbie",
      "description": "classic prawn on the BBQ"
    },
    "175f2a58-33c4-4886-920f-cb073101f104": {
      "name": "vegemite toast",
      "description": "toast + vegemite; nice"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I go about this ? (my google-foo is failing me today)

Comment: I suppose there is a good reason for why you _don't_ just define the models according to the data schema you want (i.e. `CountryDetails.recipes: dict[str, RecipeWithoutID]` or something), so there is some context missing here. Yes, this can be done, but I still think this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Can you explain why you think you need this and don't want the appropriate model definitions?

Comment: first of all id is a function in python, i would replace the name, secondly this can be done overriding or extending the json() method of BaseModel for the "to_json". for the way "from_json" you can implement a root validator

Answer (score 0):

### Note:

I spent some time drafting a solution based on the current documentation. It doesn't look like the expected solution is working as is... Possibly a bug? Will look further

### Expected Solution

> Note: This doesn't work.

You can specify json_encoding within the [model configuration](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/model_config/):

```py
class CountryDetails(BaseModel):
    name: str
    recipes: List[Recipe]
    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            # I wrote a messy lambda, you can improve
            List[Recipe]: lambda values: {v.id:{'name':v.name, 'description': v.description} for v in values}
        }
```

Code to test it out:

```
recipes = [
    Recipe(id=uuid.uuid4(), name="shrimp", description="This is shrimp"),
    Recipe(id=uuid.uuid4(), name="pizza", description="This is pizza")
]

c = CountryDetails(name="France", recipes=recipes)

# To json:
c.json()
```